# How to prohibit Angular touching (minifying) specific scripts in prod mode

Tags: angular, reactjs, typescript, angular-cli

We are building an `Angular` (v. 7) app where we also use some `React`-based widgets inside. Those `React` widgets are bundled in a `umd` node module. In dev mode everything works as expected - widgets are rendered correctly. However, in production mode something strange happens and some of the `React` widgets are rendered in a weird way.

After some experimenting I tried to include those `widgets` inside `scripts` in `angular.json` and remove its `import` from `ts` files. Then I just access it by its name via the `window['libraryName']`. Building in `prod` like this showed correct rendering (same as in `dev` mode). So, I concluded for myself that incorrect rendering happens because of the angular's minification process. If the script is left untouched everything works correctly.

Now, this solution (even though it works) is not perfect at all. First, it's quite ugly to access a library via a `window` object. And more importantly, the library is loaded as soon as the app starts loading which is unacceptable due to its size and to the fact that it's only used inside a lazy-loaded module.

I also tried to use a TypeScript dynamic `import()` and get a library this way. But that didn't work as Angular still minifies that lib when it sees that I'm importing it in one or another way.

I know this is a weird issue and I didn't manage to find anything similar to what I'm experiencing. But judging by all the facts mentioned - the best solution would be to somehow force Angular minification process to ignore that library.

p.s.
I might be wrong that it's due to minification exactly. But it's definitely due to some steps involved in the `prod` build packaging that are different from what happens in `dev` build (`ng serve`).

Those are different `angular.json` build settings and corresponding results:

```
optimization: false, buildOptimizer: true, vendorChunk: false - 33.3mb (works good)
optimization: true, buildOptimizer: false, vendorChunk: false - 17mb (not working)
optimization: true, buildOptimizer: false, vendorChunk: true - 17mb (not working)
```

React widgets library is minified by itself using webpack v.4 built-in minifier.

Comment: if you minify your react-based module using other standalone tools and include it via script, will it also fail in dev mode? if so, you need to fix it in react-based module.

Comment: @ABOS, React library is actually minified by itself using webpack v4 standard minifier. Added this info to the question.

Comment: have you tried without minifing code in react build?

Comment: Yes, tried this as well :) that was one of my thoughts that double minification could lead to problems. Didn’t work

Comment: you can use custom-webpack build in angular (https://codeburst.io/customizing-angular-cli-6-build-an-alternative-to-ng-eject-a48304cd3b21) and have your own customization logic for minimizer plugins, for example, https://webpack.js.org/plugins/terser-webpack-plugin/, exclude your react-based widget there.

Comment: Are you talking about ejecting Angular CLI?

Comment: nope, see first link on how to customize/extend build

Comment: @ABOS, this looks like it could be a good solution. Have you used this stuff before? I'm trying to configure it properly now but experiencing some issues. Could you help with it a bit?

Comment: @ Daniil, I customized some loaders for webpack before, presumably plugins works in a similar way. What thing do you want me to help you with?

Comment: @ABOS, well, since you are familiar with the problem I'm facing - I just need to ignore a certain script during the optimization phase. I created a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54607569/angular-builders-ignore-certain-script-during-in-the-optimisation-phase