# @angular-builders - ignore certain script during in the optimisation phase

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

I need to make Angular ignore a certain `js` file during the optimization phase (so that it's not optimized/minified) in `prod` build. For this purpose the `@angular-builders` package seemed like a viable solution.

I setup the `angular.json` config as follows:

```
"architect": {
            "build": {
                "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
                "options": {
                    "customWebpackConfig": {
                        "path": "./extended-webpack.config.js",
                        "mergeStrategies": {
                          "optimization": "replace"
                        }
                    },
```

The build `configurations` are as follows:

```
"configurations": {
                    "production": {
                        "optimization": true,
                        "outputHashing": "all",
                        "sourceMap": false,
                        "extractCss": true,
                        "namedChunks": false,
                        "aot": true,
                        "extractLicenses": true,
                        "vendorChunk": false,
                        "buildOptimizer": true,
```

The rest of the configuration stays the same as for normal use-cases.

The `extended-webpack.config.js` looks like following:

```
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    optimization: {
        minimizer: [
            new TerserPlugin({
                exclude: ['./node_modules/<lib>/main.js']
            }),
        ],
    }
};
```

From what I see in the build the library is still minimized from the original version. Is this configuration correct for what I want to do?